# MySQL: speed up join of 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have a simple JOIN ON query, between tables `ads` and `make`, table `ads` has about 71k rows, and `make` only has 80.

but this simple query below takes between 0.98-1.1 seconds on average. Is there anyway to speed this up?

```
SELECT t2.*, COUNT(*) AS count
        FROM `ads` AS t
        JOIN (`make` AS t2)
        ON (t.make_id=t2.id)
        WHERE t.pending!=1
        GROUP BY t2.make
        ORDER BY `count` DESC
        LIMIT 24
```

**UPDATE:**

added `EXPLAIN` and i get this

```
 id |   select_type  |  table | type    |   possible_keys | key    |    key_len |   ref      |  rows  | Extra   
 1  |   SIMPLE       | t2      |    ALL |   PRIMARY       | NULL   |    NULL    |   NULL     |  80     |    Using temporary; Using filesort

 1  |   SIMPLE       | t      | ref     |  pending,make_id| make_id|    1       |dev.t.make_id|     1010     |  Using where
```

Comment: yes. empty the tables! it'll speed op. But on a more serious note. you should check the `explain`

Comment: Have you tried to put `EXPLAIN` in front of it and check out what is slow? Is `t2.make` indexed? Is `t.make_id` indexed? Is `t2.id` indexed? Is `t.pending` indexed?

Comment: also, you are ordering by count, so if you have a lot results (you need to order before you do your limit) that'll be expensive as well.

Comment: @Nanne A file/memorysort with `80` rows shouldn't be an issue (he's grouping by `t2.make`). OP: regarding your EXPLAIN you can see what it uses filesort for `t` because your columns aren't indexed. Index `t.pending` and `t.make_id`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo updated question, included `EXPLAIN` results

Comment: @h2ooooooo point, missed that bit of info :)

Comment: @user2636556 I don't know if you noticed the fact that I changed the comment where I replied to Nanne to include which columns you should add indexes on. Nanne: No worries :)

Comment: @h2ooooooo only saved 0.15 seconds. or is this normal for a table with 71k rows?

Comment: @user2636556 What does your EXPLAIN tell you now? I've worked with tables with over 1M rows, and it's been working fine and quick.

Comment: @h2ooooooo updated Q again

Comment: @user2636556 Did you also index `t2.make` (that you're grouping by), and did you make sure that `t2.id` is indexed (that you're joining on)?

Comment: @h2ooooooo yes i did. submitted my own answer below. but no idea why is works better than a JOIN ON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i have NO idea why this works better than a join ON

```
`SELECT t2.make, COUNT(t.make_id) AS Count
                                        FROM `ads` AS t, `make` AS t2
                                        WHERE t.make_id=t2.id AND t.pending!=1
                                        GROUP BY t.make_id
                                        ORDER BY Count DESC
                                        LIMIT 24`
```

but now it runs in 0.3 seconds